# Floating point madness in Java with implicit conversions?

Tags: java, floating-point

Why is that, assuming that `A` is an array of ints and `D` a double and `K` an integer,

```
int v = ((A[i+1]-A[i])/D);
K -= v;
```

yields a compilation error in Java but

```
double v = ((A[i+1]-A[i])/D);
K -= v;
```

doesn't?

Even weirder,

#### A

```
K -= ((A[i+1]-A[i])/D);
```

gives a different result than

#### B

```
K -= (int)((A[i+1]-A[i])/D);
```

This doesn't make any sense at all to me? I would always assume that A) would never compile (attempting to implicitly convert a double to integer).

Can someone elucidate me on this one?

Thanks

Comment: very first line of [JLS 15.26.2. Compound Assignment Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2): "A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once." (mainly the cast to `T`)

Answer (score 3):

The second case includes an (int) conversion, because of the definition of compound operators such as -=. See the Java Language Specification, [15.26.2. Compound Assignment Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent
>   to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1
>   is evaluated only once.

`K -= v;` is equivalent to `K = (int)((K) - (v))`, except that `K` is evaluated only once.

(A) does the subtraction in double arithmetic. (B) does the subtraction in int arithmetic, after converting to int the result of evaluating `((A[i+1]-A[i])/D)`.

Comment: Matrx is broken, a Déjà vu [:-)

Comment: You're saying that in B, the Java compiler is going to convert all the different terms of the operation to `int` first, and only then perform the computation?

Comment: No, it is only going to do the subtraction in (int). I'll edit to make it clearer.